# Serial Mark-Sweep-Compact (PSOldGen) PS stands for?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

When I searched for PSOldGen garbage collector which I saw in the gc log, I found out that it is Serial Mark-Sweep-Compact. If this gc is serial, what does PS in PSOldGen stand for? AFAIK it is Parallel scavenge. But this confuses me.

```
[Full GC [PSYoungGen: 647K->0K(60352K)] [PSOldGen: 45361K->45875K(54528K)] 46008K->45875K(114880K) [PSPermGen: 10201K->10201K(21248K)], 0.0359430 secs]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 2 collectors in JVM: young space collector and old space collector. HotSpot JVM are implementing bunch of algorithms, but only certain combination of collectors are workable.

`PSYoungGen` is a "parallel scavenge" young space GC algorithm, but its not compatible with default serial algorithm for old space (`Tenured`). `PSOldGen` is a **serial** old space algorithm which was added specifically to work with **parallel scavenge** young space algorithm - `PSYoungGen`.

You can enable parallel algorithm for old space too (`-XX:+UseParallelOldGC`), in this case you will see `PSYoungGen`, `ParOldGen` pair of algorithms at work.

You can also enable another parallel young space algorithm `-XX:+UseParNewGC`, which will tandem with default serial old space algorithm `Tenured`.

Have I lost you already? :)

You can read more about algorithms implemented in HotSpot JVM in my [blog](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/12/garbage-collection-in-hotspot-jvm.html).

Comment: Hotspot GC cheat-sheet is printed out on my desk.

Comment: Could you please update the cheat sheet with Serial Mark-Sweep-Compact (Tenured) for the first old collector? and may be add a new row for ParNew+Tenured combination? regards.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, in a way, except it really depends on how you configured your JVM command line options. The young gen GC is Parallel Scavenge and multithreaded.

Interestingly, if you start it using `-XX:+UseParallelGC` then, you'll get a serial (single-threaded) Old Gen GC. If you use `-XX:+UseParallelOldGC` then you get both a multi-threaded, parallel young gen GC and a multi-threaded, parallel old gen GC.

Source: [Java Performance](http://search.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137001040), chapter 7, *Garbage Collectors* section.

Surprising, isn't it. there's a lot of scope for tinkering here too! The Java Performance book is well worth a read!